# qt creator qt5.1 vs2010 linker error when using static library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, qt5

i have a problem when i try to use a static library which was compiled with vs2010 in qt creater with qt 5.1.
I'm using qt5.1. which was compiled with/for the vs2010 compiler.

The source for my simple library look as follows:

Lib_Test.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Lib_Test
{
  public:
    Lib_Test(void);
    ~Lib_Test(void);

    void HelloTest();
};
```

Lib_Test.cpp

```
#include "Lib_Test.h"

Lib_Test::Lib_Test(void)
{
}

Lib_Test::~Lib_Test(void)
{
}

void Lib_Test::HelloTest()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

This two files are compiled into my "Lib_Test.lib". I copied the lib and the header file to "C:/Qt/" to simplify the library calls.
My qt project file (for a c++ console application):

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = Lib_Test_Qt
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Qt
DEPENDPATH += C:/Qt

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/Qt/
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lLIB_Test
```

And finally the main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <Lib_Test.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

      Lib_Test *lb = new Lib_Test();
      lb->HelloTest();

      return a.exec();
}
```

When i try to build the project in Qt Creator i get the following error message

```
main.obj:-1: Fehler:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Lib_Test::HelloTest(void)" (?HelloTest@Lib_Test@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
main.obj:-1: Fehler:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Lib_Test::Lib_Test(void)" (??0Lib_Test@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
debug\Lib_Test_Qt.exe:-1: Fehler:LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

When i declare the HelloTest method as a static method and try to call it without creating an instance of Lib_Test i get a similar error Message

```
main.obj:-1: Fehler:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl Lib_Test::HelloTest(void)" (?HelloTest@Lib_Test@@SAXXZ) referenced in function _main
debug\Lib_Test_Qt.exe:-1: Fehler:LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What am i missing? Can someboody help? It's really frustrating right now :/.

Edit:

I tried DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS Lib_Test.lib in the msvs2010 console and all i get is:

```
Microsoft (R) COSS/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40210.01
Copytight (C) Microsoft Corporation. All right reserved


Dump of file Lib_Test.lib

File Type: LIBRARY
```

Does that mean that my library is somehow empty?? :/

Answer (score 0):

In your qmake files, change
    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -C:/Qt/ -lLib_Test
    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += C:/Qt/Lib_Test.lib

To

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/Qt/
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lLib_Test
```

Or

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -LC:/Qt/
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -l_Test
```

I think one of them should work. And don't forget to go to Build menu, then Run qmake.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, the first error, for when i try to call HelloTest as a member function, stays the same, and when i try to call HelloTest as a static function i get also a 'unresolved external symbol error'. I'll adopt your frist suggestion to my post.